# how to show company logo and name in company page from blade file

Tags: laravel

My website is for hostels and I have a spacial page for the hostel on that page. I want to show the hostel logo, name , email and phone number which I store in table with image but when I try to show it, it shows all the hostels stored in table.

I tried this code in index for passing in blade:

```
public function index()
    {
        $file = FileUpload::all();
        return view('demo',compact( 'file'));
    }
```

and I tried this for storing:

```
$file = new FileUpload();
        $file->name         = request('name');
        $file->email        = request('email');
        $file->phone        = request('phone');
        $file->address      = request('address');
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use find in your eloquent model to get particular row.

```
public function index()
{
   $hostelId = 3; // this should be a dynamic variable based on your logic
   $file = FileUpload::find($hostelId);
   return view('demo',compact( 'file'));
}
```

This will get all the result.

```
FileUpload::all();
```

This will get result based on primary id.

```
FileUpload::find($hostelId);
```

This will get result based on where clause.

```
FileUpload::where('coulmn' => $value)->first(); // first() will get single result
```